# how to get prev and child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something like this

```
<ul>
    <li>-</li>
    <li>-</li>
</ul>
<table id="foo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>-</th>
            <th>-</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And I would like to select `li` and `th` from `#foo`

```
var controls = $('#foo').find('th').end().prev().find('li').css('background','red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1kpg3f1/1/

I try add() and `addBack()`, but nothing right.

Comment: `$('#foo').prev().addBack().find('li, th').css('background','red');` - may not be accurate

Comment: why can't you run it as 2 different commands

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c1kpg3f1/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#foo').find("th").add($('#foo').prev().find('li')).css('background','red');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c1kpg3f1/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to give both `li` elements and both `th` elements a red background:

```
$('#foo').prev().find('li').css('background','red');
$('#foo').find('th').css('background','red');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c1kpg3f1/5/).

Comment: $('#foo').prev().addBack().find('li, th').css('background','red'); works for me.

Comment: @benoît why do you need them both in one line?

Comment: I use `$control.on('click'…)` can we do something like `$controls,$controls_ul.on(…)`?

Comment: @benoît that changes the context of your question. You should have asked that first, otherwise my answer would have been similar to [Arun P Johny's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357912/how-to-get-prev-and-child/26357979#comment41374299_26357912).